# how to get values from a interface in golang

Tags: php, go

I need to get values from a serialized string which generated from php code

So I use a package named:`php_serialize` to unserialize the string and then got a result of `interface{}` type .

But I have no idea how to get values inside the result.

This is code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/yvasiyarov/php_session_decoder/php_serialize"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // this string is generated from php code
    str := `a:3:{s:4:"name";s:3:"tom";s:3:"age";s:2:"23";s:7:"friends";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:"name";s:5:"jerry";}i:1;a:1:{s:4:"name";s:4:"jack";}}}`

    decoder := php_serialize.NewUnSerializer(str)

    if result, err := decoder.Decode(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

The print result is :

```
map[name:tom age:23 friends:map[0:map[name:jerry] 1:map[name:jack]]]
```

This result is a `php_serialize.PhpValue` type, which is `interface{}` type

The next step is how to get values inside the result?

such as get the `age` field and value

Comment: Assert the actual type and you are done. Work through https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 and the following. Use the `%T` verb of Printf to see the actual type if undocumented.

Comment: This can help https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch

Comment: Actual example of decoding various types can be found at [https://github.com/yvasiyarov/php_session_decoder/blob/master/php_serialize/unserialize_test.go](https://github.com/yvasiyarov/php_session_decoder/blob/master/php_serialize/unserialize_test.go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some ways to access the data:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/yvasiyarov/php_session_decoder/php_serialize"
)

func main() {
    // this string is generated from php code
    str := `a:3:{s:4:"name";s:3:"tom";s:3:"age";s:2:"23";s:7:"friends";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:"name";s:5:"jerry";}i:1;a:1:{s:4:"name";s:4:"jack";}}}`

    decoder := php_serialize.NewUnSerializer(str)

    result, err := decoder.Decode()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)

    // simple assert
    t := result.(php_serialize.PhpArray)
    // use php_seriale build in function to get string
    strVal := php_serialize.PhpValueString(t["name"])
    fmt.Println(strVal)

    // type switch in case of different valid types
    switch t := result.(type) {
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", t) // %T prints whatever type t has
    case php_serialize.PhpArray:
        fmt.Println(t)
        fmt.Println(t["name"])
        fmt.Println(t["age"])

        // should be done recursively...
        switch f := t["friends"].(type) {
        default:
            fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", f) // %T prints whatever type t has
        case php_serialize.PhpArray:
            fmt.Println(f)
            fmt.Println(f[0])
            fmt.Println(f[1])
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you some ideas.

#### Basic concept

- `php_serialize` has built in functions to convert primitives.
- Variable structures are represented with built in types which need to be used to access the structure.

Comment: thank you, your answer is good .It helped me understand type assert better

Answer (score 4):

You must assert the `result` to `map[string]interface`:

```
mResult := result.(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(mResult["name"])
```

And once more assertion for `friends`:

```
mFriends := mResult["friends"].(map[int]map[string]interface{})
```

Then use it: `mFriends[0]["name"]`